# CMake Error at modules/videoio/cmake/detect_ffmpeg.cmake:16

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake

I'm trying to build OpenCV with opencv-contrib modules as extra modules using CMake-gui in order to get Cuda DNN to work with my GPU, but I got this error :

`CMake Error at modules/videoio/cmake/detect_ffmpeg.cmake:16 (include): include could not find load file: C:/opencv_4/build/3rdparty/ffmpeg/ffmpeg_version.cmake`

How can I fix this error?

- OpenCV: 4.4.0 ( installed from source )
- Cuda: 10.0
- Cudnn:7.5
- python 3.6

Comment: Can you please provide the **full** CMake output that contains this error? Some additional context would be helpful. What version of OpenCV are you using? Did all of the `3rdparty` components get downloads properly? I.e. Is this `C:/opencv_4/build/3rdparty/ffmpeg/ffmpeg_version.cmake` a valid path on your machine?

Comment: I will update the post

Comment: Answer to your question, Yes I have the path of ffmpeg_version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this error by building and installing OpenCV 4.4.0-pre + OpenCV-contrib (cloned the projects from GitHub) and built using CMake GUI and Visual Studio 2019 (with VS 2017 as C++ toolset platform).

1. Open CMake GUI and choose the OpenCV sources and OpenCV build folder (output folder).
2. Click on Configure and choose the Visual Studio 2019 or 2017, depends on what you have.
3. Start the Configure process.
4. Set `WITH_CUDA` and `OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH` to `path/to/opencv_contrib/modules`
5. Click on Configure.
6. `WITH_CUDNN` option should now appear. Set `WITH_CUDNN` and `OPENCV_DNN_CUDA`.
7. Click on Configure.
8. Click on Generate.
9. Open `OpenCV.sln`.
10. Set Build to `Release` instead of `Debug`.
11. Right-click on `All_build` and click on build.
12. After finishing this process, click on `INSTALL` and repeat the same task (right-click and choose build).
13. Close `OpenCV.sln` solution, open CMD and write python.
14. Write `>>import cv2` and hit enter, then write `>>print(cv2.__version__)`.
15. If you get OpenCV 4-4.0-pre (or another version) that means everything should work.